# Galera cluster mysqldump technique

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I have the below setup for which I need to take a backup for.
- 5 nodes
- running MariaDB
- tables for databases use 'InnoDB'
- using Galera for clustering
- having Binary log, but I have cron job to flush (purging older than 10 or 30 days, each log file is about 1GB)
- the directory '/var/lib/mysql' within container, I guess it is the data directory, is ~33G today with 30 mysql-bin.* files

My questions:
- Should I run 'mysqldump' on all 5 nodes, or is it OK to run on only one node?
- How can I do incremental backup? Should I stop the cron job of purging binary log older than 10 or 30 days?
- Any suggestion?

Kindly help.

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 1):

Galera mostly obviates the need for binlogs and dumps.  Your 5 nodes are 5 copies of the data.  If any one of the nodes dies, it can (and will) be reconstructed from one of the surviving nodes.  (Cf "SST")

You *could* take a node out of the cluster, dump it by any means, then put it back in.  This would provide you with a recovery path is you lost all the nodes.

If all the nodes are in the same datacenter, you are vulnerable to natural disasters (wildfire, earthquake, etc).

In writing out disaster recovery plans, you will discover the answer to "how many days of binlogs to keep".

Comment: Thanks for the response Rick, so the ideal way to take mysqldump is 1>Take a node out of the cluster 2>Take mysqldump from that node 3>Put the node back in the cluster. Also for incremental backups I can just copy the bin logs directly from one of the nodes in the cluster(without removing the node) and then purge the backed up log?

Comment: @AshishVerma - I strongly suspect that the binlogs cannot be copied from one node to another.  See XtraBackup.

Comment: When I take the node out of the cluster for backup, what happens to the transsactions running on that node, Do the transactions rollback or they commit? For a long running query on the node being taken out of the cluster, what would happen to that transaction? Also, for incremental backups I think I can just copy the binary logs from the backup node as I would only need to build only one node in case of total failure of cluster.

Comment: @AshishVerma - Taking the node out is more graceful than that.  "Normally", when you bring the node back into the Cluster, it will do an "IST" (Incremental State Transfer) using stuff in the "gcache" and be quite fast.  The fall back is to do an "SST".  Study those in the documentation.  (The choice between IST and SST is automatic.)

Comment: Thanks Rick, I will need to study the documentation for planning a solution as per our environment.

Comment: Use XtraBackup or preferably Mariabackup for physical backup. Yu can do full or incremental backup using these tools. Should use --galera-info option while backing up the data.